# exporting database and wordpress theme not functioning properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm to get migrate a website I populated for a friend from my server to his.  Unfortunatly, the migration process isn't working the way it normally should.

Does anyone have an idea to what would cause this wordpress site to break and for all the navigation to direct to the original site?

Even my wp admin redirects to orginal page

Here's the site I hosted it on for demo: http://www.designobvio.us/avproduktor/

Here's the site I'm trying to migrate it too http://avprodukter.com/

I have no idea why avprodukters isnt working: steps I took.

Exported database from designobvio.us/avproduktor
Replaced all links with designobvio.us to avproduktor
imported database to http://www.avprodukter.com/
installed wp and now i'm here

I'm going to repeat this process again to see maybe I was just dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has some special steps you have to take when migrating it to a different domain.  Namely, you have to change the Blog URL from the administrative interface prior to moving the site.

There is a reference in the database to the old domain and that is what it is using to build the URL's.  Without starting over, you can use a tool like phpMyAdmin, or even the MySQL console to change that setting in the database.

The two settings you would have to change in the database are in the `wp_options` table (assuming tables are prefixed with `wp_`).  The two `option_name`s are `siteurl` and `home`.  Both of those should contain the old domain; you need to update them to reflect the new URL.

See [Moving Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server) from the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) for the full directions and steps to take in different scenarios.

You could start over and follow the steps from the link above, or you can just change those 2 values in the database and then you should be set.

Comment: Your method did the trick. (so far so good) ::crosses fingers:: Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

> Replaced all links with designobvio.us to avproduktor...

How did you do that? In phpmyadmin? If by a text editor with a database dump, you broke some serialized data. Use the queries below.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

And did you reset permalinks?

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

Comment: I believe i fixed all the permalinks however the site is totally missing backgrounds and what not.  where would i run those queries.  I replaced all the links with a text editor btw

Comment: Using a text editor to find/replace breaks serialized data. Use the queries above in phpymyadmin in an original copy of the database. And check for hardcoded URLs in style.css and other theme files.